# How to list the available documents for RshowDoc()

Tags: r

I recently learned R has a function called `RShowDoc()` that lets you specify and open package documentation and R help files.

I had fun with some examples but have been limited by document file names that I know. Is there a way to list all the available documents I could use with this function, something like `ls()`.